# Apply function to every array key

Tags: php, arrays, cassandra

I am using Cassandra and I have saved some byte representations as ID. Everything is working fine, however that data (id) is no good for output.

```
$users = $db->get('1');
echo '<pre>';
print_r($users);
die();
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [��� X��W��c_   ] => Array
        (
            [id] => ��� X��W��c_    
            [name] => steve
            [surname] => moss
        )

    [�*B�X��y�~p��~] => Array
        (
            [id] => �*B�X��y�~p��~
            [name] => john
            [surname] => doe
        )

)
```

As you can see ID's are some wierd characters, it's because they are byte representations in database. They actually look like `\xf5*B\xa0X\x00\x11\xe1\x99y\xbf~p\xbc\xd1~`.

In PHPCASSA there is function `CassandraUtil::import();` to which I can pass these bytes and it will return guid. It works fine, but I want my array to automatically converted from bytes to guids.

Only option I find is looping through every item in array and assigning new value to it. Somehow I think that it is not the best approach. Is there any other ways to do this?

TL;DR
Have array with bytes like above, need to use `CassandraUtil::import();` on array keys and id's to get readable id's. What is the most effective way of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Sorry, only saw the top level array key, I think you would have to run the function below as well as another one after:

```
function cassImportWalkRecur(&$item, $key)
{
    if ($key == 'id') 
        $item = CassandraUtil::import();
}

$array = array_walk_recursive($array, 'cassImportWalkRecur');
```

That should apply it to the ID fields. If you need to check the data first, there maybe a way to detect the encoding, but I am not sure how to do that.

---

You should be able to create a function and use [`array_walk`](http://php.net/array_walk) to traverse the array and update the keys. Something like:

```
function cassImportWalk($item, &$key)
{
    $key = CassandraUtil::import();
}

$array = array_walk($array, 'cassImportWalk');
```

Untested (also you may have to change the CassandraUtil usage), but *should* work.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried, however it does not work since not all elements are like ID's. Would it be good idea to use 'try' so it will do so only to elements he can change?

Comment: The `array_walk`, should only affect the top level array. For the inner array, we may have to do a different function / take a different process. Gonna update my answer. @Qmal, updated.

Comment: And as far as the try is concerned, does it throw an exception? If it does, go ahead and wrap it in a try, and catch / handle the error if need be.

Comment: I don't know if changing the key like this is a good idea. From the documentation : "Only the **values of the array may potentially be changed**; its structure cannot be altered, i.e., the programmer cannot add, unset or reorder elements. If the callback does not respect this requirement, the behavior of this function is undefined, and unpredictable."

Comment: Yea, I seemed to have skimmed over that, might be worth testing before diving head deep into it though.

Comment: Be aware the array_walk functions return bool, not the altered array. The array is passed in by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding the question this can be done simply and cleanly like so:

```
$users = $db->get('1');
$keys  = array_keys($users);
$readableKeys = array_map("CassandraUtil::import",$keys);
foreach($users as $currentKey => $subArray) {
   $readableKey = array_shift($readableKeys);
   $subArray['id'] = $readableKey;
   $users[$readableKey] = $subArray;
   unset($users[$currentKey]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would `array_flip()` all keys and values, then `array_walk()` and apply my function, before doing a final `array_flip()`.

Comment: No. The values are not guaranteed to be unique or suitable as keys.